# Not able to search fields using SOSL for Case module

Tags: apex, sosl, case-object, dynamic-sosl

I am trying to fire a SOSL query in Apex to find phone number exits in Case module. Below is the example of one of the cases that I am trying to search.

[image]

I am using following query to search the record

> FIND {503} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Case(ContactMobile,ContactPhone,
>   CaseNumber where ( ContactMobile != null  or ContactPhone!=null))

Even though there is a `ContactMobile` and `ContactField` exists in `Case` module it does not returning any row

[image]

However , if I search the same using SOQL then it returns the results

[image]

Both `ContactMobile` and `ContactField` are read only field and has the proper read only permission , not sure what is the problem here

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't search all standard fields in Salesforce. [Searchable Objects and Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields.htm&type=0) contains links to documents that state which standard fields are searchable in Lightning and Classic. Note that Contact Mobile and Contact Phone are not searchable fields. These act as a type of "formula" field, and fields that don't actually store a value can't be searched. One possible solution would be to create a custom field and copy the values to the custom field via trigger or Process Builder so that they become indexed and searchable.